# Remove Space from URL

Tags: forms, url, search, get

I Working on implementing search on my website. I am just passing in the search keyword to java. the url is being formatted and contructed in java. My stuff works fine if I pass in single word say "finance".

But if I have a space in my search keyword like 
"finance estimate" then its throwing error. I am sending the search keyword in a form/ GET method.

How should I take out the space and look like one word

This is the error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.AbstractFrontController.doPost(AbstractFrontController.java:72)
    at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.AbstractFrontController.doGet(AbstractFrontController.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.invokeNextFilter(AbstractFilter.java:65)
    at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.XSSParameterEncodingFilter.doFilter(XSSParameterEncodingFilter.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3393)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2046)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
```

Comment: *How* do you create the GET request, exactly? The error itself comes from not URL-encoding the search term, but it depends on your current code how to fix that.

Comment: String query = "&B=0&Btk=AllText&Btt=" + searchTO.getSearchTerm()+ "; String context = "/something/servlet?"; String url = protocol + getDomain() + context + query; This is how i constructing the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace spaces with %20, but that only helps with spaces and won't escape other characters. What you really need to do is use a [URL-escaping function](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).